# Can you store and arrary in side a varbiable

Tags: python, arrays

Hi so I am new to python and I am creating this program where the user puts something in with the input function and if that input is equal to a variable something happens. My question is can you create a variable with a list of choice in the variable. Something I tried earlier and it did not work is down below.

```
vol_cube = ["CV" , "cv", "Cube_vol"]
```

So this did not work and my question is how do I have something similar to this.

Comment: That is valid Python code... what do you mean it "did not work"?

Comment: so when ever a user types anything in that array python does not seem to take  it as a valid input and noting happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
vol_cube = ["CV" , "cv", "Cube_vol"] # creates the list

while True: # loops until the user gives a correct input
    user_input = input('Please enter something: ') 

    if user_input in vol_cube:  # if their input is a value stored in vol_cube
        break # breaks the loop
```